# Error: Cannot find module 'connect' - Meteor

Tags: meteor

In my meteor app I'm getting this error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'connect'
```

I haven't installed connect in my local server and its working fine there.The issue occurred when the code was moved to server. Why is this happening ? What else data should I provide for anyone to help me !

Comment: Have you tried `npm install [-g] connect`?

Comment: you are not supposed to get such errors if you don't `require('connect')` directly in your code. Please provide more context about your app.

Comment: @Nidhinz can you give a bit more info on how you are using it? (If you are). Have you considered using iron-router for server side rendering?

Comment: I just stopped meteor and then restarted it..and now the issue is fixed..donno what actually was the problem.